# How can I ask the SQL server if I have permissions on something? (insert, update,etc)

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for the database layer that validates the connection string's user has update/insert/read permissions. insert/rollback would create extra gaps in the identity column or launch triggers. for read permissions selecting against the table creates load/work on the sql database and updates when the table was last searched in the statistics. How do I programmatically ask sql server the current user's permissions on an object/table/view/stored procedure/etc.

I imagine it's in the system tables somewhere.

Comment: If your data design depends on no gaps in number you have bigger problems you need to solve first.

Comment: Agree with above comment. Anyway think there are system stored procs that would let you get this info. Failing that SQLDMO library.

Comment: neither my data nor my application depend on it, it's a personal preference, not to cause gaps when not necessary or when there's a better way to accomplish things

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can ask for each permission individually using [HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx):

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('<table>', 'OBJECT', 'SELECT');
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('<table>', 'OBJECT', 'UPDATE');
...
```

Or you can ask for all your permissions using [fn_my_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('<table>', 'object');
```

Comment: +1 both of these are good information to have.  in sql server 2005, it's `SELECT Has_Perms_By_Name('<table>','OBJECT','SELECT')`

Comment: Thanks Maslow, I fixed the syntax and args

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following stored proc

```
EXEC sp_table_privileges 
   @table_name = ' <table name> '
```

It should give you want you are looking for

Comment: +1 this shows a nice list of everyone's permissions on the table